# The hyperbolic metric on the punctured disk induced by a covering by the upper plane

Tags: proof-verification, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

I am reading a book on Riemann surfaces. The section I am currently reading is trying to define the hyperbolic metric on the punctured disk $D\backslash\{0\}$ in $\mathbb C$.

First let $H$ be the upper half-plane with the hyperbolic metric $\frac{1}{y^2}dzd\bar z$, then use the map
$$z\mapsto e^{iz}$$ to induce a metric on $D\backslash\{0\}$. The exact words are

> Consider now the map
>   $$z\mapsto e^{iz}=w$$
>   of $H$ onto $D\backslash\{0\}$. This local homeomorphism (which is actually a covering) induces on $D\backslash\{0\}$ the metric
>   $$\frac{1}{|w|^2(\log|w|^2)^2}dwd\bar w$$
>   with potential
>   $\frac{1}{4}\log\log|w|^{-2}$...

However my own calculation gives a different answer:

Suppose the induced metric is $\lambda^2(w)dwd\bar w$. Since $F:z\mapsto e^{iz}$ is locally invertible, we find a sufficiently short path $\gamma$ in $D\backslash\{0\}$ such that there exist $U\subset H, V\subset D$ such that $F$ restricted to U is a homeomorphism onto $V$ and $\gamma\subset V$. Hence we have
$$\int_{\gamma}\lambda(w)|dw|=\int_{F^{-1}\gamma}|dz|/{\rm Im} z$$
Let $w=Fz=e^{iz}$, then
$$\int_{F^{-1}\gamma}\lambda(Fz)|F'(z)||dz|=\int_{F^{-1}\gamma}|dz|/{\rm Im} z$$
This must hold for all $\gamma$, hence
$$\lambda(Fz)|F'(z)||dz|=|dz|/{\rm Im} z\implies\lambda(Fz)=\frac{1}{|F'(z)|{\rm Im}z}$$
Note that $Fz=w,\ F'(z)=ie^{iz}=iw,\ {\rm Im}z=-\log|w|$, whence
$$\lambda(w)=\frac{1}{-|w|\log|w|}$$
and the metric should be
$$\lambda^2(w)dwd\bar w=\frac{1}{|w|^2(\log|w|)^2}dwd\bar w$$
which is different from the one in the book (a missing exponent 2 of $|w|$.

So where did I go wrong? Or is the book wrong?